# jquery animate first time run not sliding

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've got a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weaveoftheride/rS9Ds/15/)

Basically the first time you hover, I want .caption-2 to gradually slide, not  'jump' up. After the first time you hover, everything is fine.

Any idea how to achieve this?

html

```
<div class="caption-img">
    <div class="headline">
        <h2>You should Study here</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="caption-2">
        <p>Learning at a place puts you in the driving seat as you set off on the journey
            to your dream career. Whether you want to become a chef, a mechanic, a builder,</p>
        <p>Learning at nice place puts you in the driving seat as you set off on the journey
            to your dream career. Whether you want to become a chef, a mechanic, a builder,</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(".caption-img").hover(function() {
    $(".headline").hide();
    $(".caption-2").show().stop().animate({"top" : "0px"});
}, function() {
    $( ".caption-2").stop().animate({"top" : "250px"});
    setTimeout(function() {
        $( ".caption-2").hide();
        $( ".headline").show();
    }, 300);
});
```

css

```
.headline {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 154, 202, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;
}
.caption-2 {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 154, 202, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.caption-img {
    height: 320px;
    position: relative;
    background: #E9EAEC url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Northwest-relief_HazeltonMountains.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
}

.caption-2 {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.caption-2` has no initial `top` CSS value. jQuery `.animate()` needs a numeric value at each end of the animation to successfully animate an element. Simply set the initial `top` style for `.caption-2`:

```
.caption-2 {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 154, 202, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Also, don't use `setTimeout()` to toggle your headings. Since `.animate()` takes a callback function; a function to invoke when the animation is complete, you can use that:

```
$(".caption-img").hover(function() {
    $(".headline").hide();
    $(".caption-2").show().stop().animate({"top" : "0px"});
}, function() {
    $( ".caption-2").stop().animate({"top" : "250px"}, 400, function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $( ".headline").show();
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8prbyyph/6/)